# How can i run Alienware command Center on ubuntu

Tags: windows, wine, alienware

as i can run Alienware command Center in ubuntu on my alienware 17R5, i've been trying for a long time but i have only found one .exe and wine won't let me run it. Someone has managed to do it. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasWard Do you know if I can control my hardware from an Alienware laptop in some other way?

Comment: I do not know, as I do not have an Alienware laptop.  Someone else might be able to answer that question, but that's not the question you're asking.  (my comment is converted to an answer for now)

Comment: What settings do you want to configure using AlienWare Command Center? We can provide you way of doing that using additional apps and commands.

Comment: @Someone What most interests me is the control of fans and if it is possible to control the LEDs of my laptop since the fans start when the pc is already at a very high temperature

Comment: When I close the lid of my `Alienware x15 R1`, the bright LED lights at the back stay on, as if its not going into a proper sleep, like it does on Windows. I need my LEDs to sync with the Ubuntu sleep process.

Answer (score 1):

Alienware Command Center does not work on Ubuntu, nor does it work on Wine as it needs hardware level access that Wine does not provide. ACC is a Windows only piece of software.